# Can't set border size in scrbook document

Tags: margins, geometry, scrbook

I'm trying to set page margins in my document, but nothing I tried actually worked.
For example I tried

```
\usepackage[total={17cm,25cm}, top=3cm, left=2cm, includefoot]{geometry}
```

but didnt worked at all (nothing changed). Here is my document preamble:

```
\documentclass[
  oneside,
  12pt, a4paper,
  footinclude=true,
  headinclude=true,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\setlength\parindent{1cm}
```

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 1):

Package `classicthesis` sets the page layout using `typearea`. So change the margins to your needs after loading `classicthesis`.

```
\documentclass[
  oneside,
  12pt, a4paper,
  %footinclude=true,
  %headinclude=true,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[total={17cm,25cm}, top=3cm, left=1cm, includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parindent{1cm}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Some text}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note that the KOMA-Script options `footinclude=true,headinclude=true` can be removed if you set the page layout by package `geometry`.

[image]